# jQuery datepicker disable sundays & specific array of dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I've gotten pretty far with this but stuck on the last part. I basically just need to disable all sundays and then be able to add dates to an array to also be disabled, I know the code to disable each individually but when I try to put them together I either get sundays with the array of dates selectable or the other way around. The two parts I need to join to have the array and sundays disable are in the beforeshowdays functions, I know I can't have two I just put both in so you can see what I'm trying. Thanks for any help

```
<script>
    var array = ["2016-08-29","2013-03-15","2013-03-16"]
</script>

<script>  

$( function() {

var today = new Date();

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 0), ''];
    },
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
       var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    },
    //beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: today.getHours() >= 14 ? 2 : 1,
    maxDate: '+1m',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $('#checkout_attribute_1').val(dateText);
    }
  });
 } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
var array = ["2016-08-29", "2013-03-15", "2013-03-16"]

$(function() {
  var today = new Date();
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
      if (contains(array,string)) {
        debugger;
        return [false, '']
      } else {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 0), ''];
      }
    },
    //beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: today.getHours() >= 14 ? 2 : 1,
    maxDate: '+1m',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $('#checkout_attribute_1').val(dateText);
    }
  });
});

function contains(a, obj) {
    var i = a.length;
    while (i--) {
       if (a[i] === obj) {
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9hrhyd4q/

Comment: You are fantastic thanks buddy really appreciate your help!

Comment: Happy to help, have a great day !

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yyyy-mm-dd', date);
    if (day == 0){
      return [false];
    }
    else if(array.indexOf(string) != -1){
      return [false];
    }
    else{
      return [true];
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's not working unfortunately, the datepicker wont open at all when I try this